# Can someone explain the `strides` parameter of YuvImage?

Tags: android, yuv

I'm trying to read a byte array into a [YuvImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html), but am having trouble understanding what the `strides` parameter means. Can anyone help (preferably with an example?) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an description of stride for yuv videos:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe that helps. If you don't know whether the pictures you want to read has such a stride (or which size it is) it might be a problem...I have no idea how common it is or not...

good luck :-)